# vectorizing histogram on matrix rows in matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram

Hello I need to calculate a histogram for every row in a big matrix.
For the first row for example I get this:

```
AA = hist(symbolic_data(1,:), 1:8);
```

With `symbolic_data(1,:)=[7 6 7 8 7]`, I get `AA=[0 0 0 0 0 1 3 1]`.

Of course this is easy using a simple for loop, but my symbolic_data matrix is really big.
Is there a way to vectorize this.
I've been fiddling with `bsxfun`, but I can't make it work.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

From Matlab help:

> N = hist(Y) bins the elements of Y into 10 equally spaced containers
>       and returns the number of elements in each container.  If Y is a
>       matrix, hist works down the columns.

so:

```
AA = hist(symbolic_data', 1:8);
```

will do what you want

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by @Mercury](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20975393/2586922) is the way to go. But if you want to do it with `bsxfun`:

1. If you only have integer values, use

   ```
   bin_centers = 1:8;
   AA = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@eq, permute(symbolic_data,[2 3 1]), bin_centers(:).')));
   ```
2. If the values are not necessarily integer:

   ```
   bin_centers = 1:8;
   AA = squeeze(sum( bsxfun(@le, permute(symbolic_data,[2 3 1]), bin_centers(:).'+.5) &...
        bsxfun(@gt, permute(symbolic_data,[2 3 1]), bin_centers(:).'-.5) ));
   ```